# Extra text comes from shell_exec command when executed from php

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, scripting, s3cmd

I am using s3cmd to get files from AWS to my ubuntu server.

```
s3cmd get s3://bucket/filename newfilename
```

It works fine when run from terminal of ubuntu.

But when I run from php like below

```
$query1 = 's3cmd get s3://bucket/filename newfilename';
$q1 = serialize(shell_exec($query1));
$data2 = array( 'data' => $q1);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $data2 );
```

It works but response from json_encode it concatenated with extra text.

```
{"data":"s:122:\"File s3:............
```

What is s:122 and how to remove this. I am not looking for sub_string though.

Comment: Why do you serialize value? `s:122` is length of value returned by `shell_exec($query1)`

Comment: if i dnt serialize value, output comes as null

Comment: what does `shell_exec($query1)` return?

Comment: File s3://bucket/folder/ih0wOlM4f8 saved as 'tempmedia/ih0wOlM4f8' (4842585 bytes in 4.3 seconds, 1090.63 kB/s)

Comment: So what output is null?

Comment: oh ok...got it...I don't need to serialize it.

Comment: Please add an answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `serialize` some value - in a result string there's type of value and value itself. `s:122`, you asked about, says that values is a **s**tring with length `122`. So if you don't want this string appear - don't serialize value.